# Cannot Use Autosum on cells that Contain Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have cells that have `IF` formulas in them. Excel won't let me autosum the results of those. It's as if Excel does not recognize those cells as numbers. Granted, numbers do *show*, but in *actuality* the cells contain formulas. Any help to autosum cells that contain formulas would be great.

The cells that are being ignored by autosum have this as a formula:  `=IF(G15=1,"5.06",IF(G15=2,"12.92",IF(G15=3,"20.78",0)))`
This formula appears to be working just fine.

*Also*, when I click into the cell where I try to do autosum, it 'tells' me it did it, by correctly showing: `=SUM(O5:O21)`. BUT, the 'answer' I see, is '0'.

Comment: Jonno has given me the answer to this. Thanks Jonno!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is because you are formatting your output values as strings instead of numbers (You are using `"` around the value).

Try changing your formula to:

```
=IF(G15=1,5.06,IF(G15=2,12.92,IF(G15=3,20.78,0)))
```

this should treat the outputs as numbers and they will be correctly added up.

Comment: MY BAD! I posted a comment back that it didn't work and I didn't copy the = part of it. Editing my comment now to say Thanks a bunch Jonno, you saved me!

Comment: @Alisa Are you sure you copied it exactly, with the equals sign? I've tested it, with SUM as well, and it's working fine. http://imgur.com/ZyIYy9K.gif

Comment: @Alisa Just saw your update, glad it's working :) Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped :)

Comment: Hi. I posted as a guest, can you tell me where to accept it? Also, I now need to know how to make nothing at all appear with that formula instead of a 'FALSE'. Do you know how to do that? Not sure if I need to post this in a new question?

Comment: @Alisa There should be a tick on the left of the answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png. The formula I posted should show 0 instead of FALSE, unless you removed that part or haven't included it in your other formulas? -- IF(G15=3,20.78,**0**)

Comment: I took out both the '0' because I want the cell to be blank. And that is what made the "FALSE" appear. Do you know it's possible to just have it be blank? All those zeros are messing with my eye sight. lol.

Comment: @Alisa Use `""` instead :), an empty string

Comment: Okay, perfect. You're awesome. Thanks and peace.